# Add/Remove attribute with checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I load from my database an user with permissions that looks like this:

```
this.current = {
    firstname: "Jack",
    lastname: "Sparrow",
    permissions: {
         0: {id: 3, name: "Perm3"},
         1: {id: 1, name: "Perm1"}
    }
};
```

---

I also have the full list of permissions:

```
this.permissions = {
    0: {id: 1, name: "Perm1"},
    1: {id: 2, name: "Perm2"},
    2: {id: 3, name: "Perm3"},
    3: {id: 4, name: "Perm4"}
};
```

---

I would like to manage user's permissions using checkboxes:

- When `checked`, permission is added to `current.permissions`
- When `!checked`, permission is removed from `current.permissions`

Each permission is unique, and can't be put 2 times in `current.permissions`

---

I wrote this piece of code, I guess I should use `ng-checked` directive, but I don't know how...

```
<p>{{current.firstname}} {{current.lastname}} permissions:</p>
<div ng-repeat="p in permissions">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked=""></input>{{p.name}}
</div>
```

---

Can you help me? 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [one possible way](https://plnkr.co/edit/SUdqJMy7gDFKgTQH12fl?p=preview) to do it.

## Main ideas:

**indexOfById**

The `indexOfById` function is similar to `indexOf` - it takes a permission object, and return its index in the user's permissions array (or -1 if it does not exist).

```
Array.prototype.indexOfById = function(obj) {
    var idx = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (this[i].id === obj.id) {
        idx = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return idx;
  };
```

**triggerPermission**

`triggerPermission` will be called when a checkbox is clicked, and it will use `indexOfById` to determine whether to add or remove the permission.

```
triggerPermission = function(perm) {
    console.log(perm.name + ' changed')
    var idx = $scope.current.permissions.indexOfById(perm);
    if (idx === -1) {
      $scope.current.permissions.push(perm);
    } else {
      console.log('splice! ' + idx);
      $scope.current.permissions.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  };
```

- I used `ngChecked` to pre-check the permissions the user already has, and that's why I used `ngClick` instead of `ngChange` to trigger the permission add\remove (the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) says `ngChange` requires `ngModel` but `ngChecked` cannot be used with `ngModel`).

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

I've made this [little working solution for you](http://jsfiddle.net/wTZYn/312/)

Provide a function, that will add that permission to your current user.

Something like this:

```
$scope.addPermission = function(permission) {
    if (permission.checked) {
        $scope.current.permissions.push(permission)
    } else {
        var index = $scope.permissions.indexOf(permission);
        $scope.current.permissions.splice(index, 1);     
    }
}
```

and in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="p in permissions">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="p.checked" ng-checked="" ng-change="addPermission(p)"></input>{{p.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: No, it will fail. You can't use ngChange like this.

Comment: You were correct, I've missed the `ng-model` bit, updated my asnwer

Comment: It seems you don't check if the permission is already in current.permissions before pusing it, right? Moreover, when we unchecked a permission, it is the last that is removed, not the good one.

Comment: My mistake about the `pop` method, use `splice` instead, I've updated my answer. And no I don't check for existing permissions.

Comment: There are still bugs. Thanks anyway.